# Not able to install packages using pip in python

Tags: python-3.x, pip

i am using

python --version

```
Python 3.7.4
```

pip --version

```
pip 19.0.3 from c:\users\lijin.durairaj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

now, i try to install packages using pip, like this

```
python -m pip install --user requests
```

but when i execute this command i am getting error like this

[image]

i tried to install the packages along with the proxy set, like this

```
pip install --proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port requests
```

but i am getting the same error, could someone help me on how to solve it, thanks

**UPDATE-1**

I even tried to navigate to the scripts directory and do a pip install, like this

```
C:\Users\lijin.durairaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install matplotlib
```

but i am getting the same error

Comment: Safe to assume you're behind some corporate security?

Comment: yes, i am behind corporate proxy but i have set the proxy for npm and i am able to download new packages using npm but i am not able to download packages using pip

Comment: Ask your sysadmin to adapt proxy rules, obviously the proxy cuts all http requests from pip, even the scan for available dists doesn't come through the proxy.

Comment: Alternatively, you could of course download packages manually or consider if a distribution like `Anaconda` that comes with many packages already installed serves your needs